# Would this code cause a panic after GC in Go1.5?

Tags: go, garbage-collection, goroutine

```
package main

import "time"

var x = []string{}

func main() {
    go func() {
        for {
            y := x
            y = append(y, "aa")
        }
    }()
    go func() {
        for {
           x = []string{"123"}
        }
    }()
    for {
        time.Sleep(1)
    }
}
```

guess like when x (for example, the address of 123) is not really assigned to y, and x is assigned to a new address like 124.
and just this time gc happened, would the address of 123 be recycled and cause a panic?

Comment: you should post panic output here. Most likely because you modify x without any synchronization from 2 goroutines. Assigning to slice is not atomic operation.

Comment: i have run this sample code for 5 minutes in my mac pro(i5 cpu) but receive no panic. @kostya

Comment: You're also blocking the STW GC phase with your busy loop. Sleeping for 1 nanosecond is only burning CPU.

Comment: if it panic in my computer, i won't ask this question. but, i know it should panic as the reason you post.   @kostya

Comment: but even i use time.Sleep(1 * time.Second). it still has not panic for 5minutes in my computer.   and @khrm say it would not panic at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. First of all, x has a global scope. So GC won't happen until a new value with new address is assign to it.

Now when a new value is assign, two things can happen:

1. Goroutine assigning y to x happens. It get assign to y. Then no GC will happen.
2. It will get new value with new address before first step happens.

I don't know what you are trying to do. But there's no panic even if goroutine runs simultaneously. X always has a value.

Since you asked that whether assignment is atomic: No normal assignment is atomic.

Comment: i want to know if "y := x" is atomic? if it is not.   _italic_ **bold** `mov eax  123,  mov y eax`   then eax has the value of 123.... and x was point to 124, just this time, gc happened,   gc find the address of 123 is free, so it recycled 123....then y was assigned 123 which is recycled?!

Comment: No normal assignment is atomic in go, Or atleast guaranteed to be atomic. But it won't make your program panic.

Comment: i := new(int32)
 atomic.StoreInt32(i, 100) //atomic
checkmate

Comment: @Darigaaz That's what I wrote. No normal assignment is atomic.

Comment: Yes. There's data race because you changing x value and assigning it also. So there's a race condition. But it's not alright in production code. And it won't cause panic for your sample. But code isn't correct.

Comment: so,why gc not happen. and recycle the memory of 123?

Comment: It collects the memory of only those which aren't assign to any variable. In this case, either it is assign to y or x.  While y := x isn't atomic and x value can get updated, there's always some value in x. If gc collects 123, y can get new value. If not then old value.

Comment: In short, only those things are gced who aren't assign to any value. Here if it has been assign to y, then there's no case for it being gc. It can only be GC if it isn't assign to any variable.

Answer (score 1):

"is not really assigned" - what, there is no such thing in go.

Your code has a race condition `go run -race`, it writes to "x", reads from "x" and grows "x"'s slice at the same time.

"y := x" is not atomic in general, it depends on value, but it is not atomic for slice/interface{}/map/struct for sure. There is sync.atomic package for atomic primitives.

Comment: It has race condition, but it won't panic.